# Replace blank space with %20 in ajax script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Upon click, button name is inserted into ajax code and content loaded into div from page.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function()
    {
    $("div").load("page.php?id="+$(this).attr('name')););
  });
});

<Button name="this button">one button</button>
```

But my button name contains blank space and only first word is read into page.php

How to replace blank space with %20 ?
Somehow, I am not able to use replace method with this.attr

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, use `encodeURIComponent`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function() {
    const name = encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('name')); // it will encode blank space with %20
    $("div").load("page.php?id="+name));
  });
});
```

Comment: This, but I would suggest not creating variables you're only going to use it once. `$('div').load('page.php?id=' + encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('name')));`